# laravel pivot table column not found while try to update

Tags: laravel-5, pivot

Problem is when I try to update the `book` table, it shows error

> unknown column 'publisher'

I have a `book_publisher` pivot table.

What code do I have to write and where do I have to write it?

```
class Book extends Model
{


  //  protected table='book';
    public function authors()
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Author::class)->withPivot('type');
    }

    // public function author($type)
    // {
    //
    //   return $this->authors()->where('type', $type)->first();
    // }
    public function author()
    {

      return $this->authors()->where('type', 'Author')->first();


    }
    public function illustrator()
    {

      return $this->authors()->where('type', 'Illustrator')->first();
    }
    public function translator()
    {

      return $this->authors()->where('type', 'Translator')->first();
    }
    public function editor()
    {

      return $this->authors()->where('type', 'Editor')->first();
    }


    // foreach ($book->authors as $author)
    // {
    //     $author->type;
    // }

    public function publishers()
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Publisher::class);
    }
}
```

bookcontroller

```
public function edit($id)
    {
      $book=Book::findOrFail($id);
      $category=Category::pluck('name', 'id');
      $publishers=Publisher::all();
      foreach($publishers as $publisher)
      {
        $publisher->id=$publisher->name;
      }
      return view('books.edit', compact('book','category','publishers'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

      $book=Book::findOrFail($id);
      $book->Update($request->all());
      Book::find($id)->publisher()->updateExistingPivot($request->only('publisher_id'));
      return redirect('books');
    }
```

Please also tell if I have to edit edit.blade.php as well.

Comment: Your question is unclear and lacks any code to explain your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check these ways

```
$books = Book::find($id);
$books->publisher()->updateExistingPivot('publisher_id',
['publisher_id' => publisher_id],false));
```

or something like this

```
$books = Book::find($id);
$publisher = $books->publisher;
$publisher->pivot->publisher_id = $request->publisher_id;
$publisher->pivot->save();
```